# Android studio - The view is not constraiined it only has designtime positions so it will jump to (0,0) unless you add constraints

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The view is not constraiined it only has designtime positions so it will jump to (0,0) unless you add constraints.

Hi there could anybody help me with this? im loading up my project on Android studio and this keeps coming up? Any easy options to get rid of this error so i can connect my phone and use it?

Comment: Let's add constrain if you use ConstraintLayout else you can use LinnearLayout, RelativeLayout,...

Comment: [this may help you](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Constrains]Find the dots on the center of the edge of the view and pull the arrow to the edege of its parent view. You have to just do it for two sides (left/right) and(top/bottom).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding constraints to every view as you place them in the layout, you can move each view into the positions you desire, and then click Infer Constraints to automatically create constraints.
view more here
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html